# CORS for reCAPTCHA

Tags: google-chrome, cors, cross-domain, recaptcha

I'm working on a site that I want to include Google's reCAPTCHA on.

If I add the following `<script>` tag to my `<head>`:

`<script crossorigin="anonymous" src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'>
</script>`

I get the following error:

`Access to Script at 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Okay, fine, fair enough. I can always disable CORS on Chrome when working on localhost. But the domain is www.google.com. I don't really feel comfortable sending an access-control-allow-origin header to anything that's on google's root domain - that feels like a security hole you could drive a bus through.

How do I get around this with a reasonable production setting for dealing with cross origin concerns here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

Your page just needs to run the script. It has no need to ask for elevated privileges so your JS can access more information about it. If it threw an error then you wouldn't have access to Google's servers in order to correct it anyway.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I had added that because it was throwing an error but I couldn't read it -- I assume because of something about the webpack dev server I was running. Thanks!